# Qt OpenGL dynamic vs. desktop

Tags: qt, opengl

What is the difference between Qt versions with dynamic and desktop OpenGL? http://tver-soft.org/qt64

Comment: I think it's the difference between using Angle (openglES2.0 implemented on top of directX) or the actual openGL installed

Comment: I don't know what "tver-soft" is, but I _strongly_ recommend that you download from the official Qt site: http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

Comment: official Qt site doesn't have the 64bit version for VS2010 :( Why so strongly?

Comment: @user2449761 Because random websites that claim to provide pre-packaged exes for other organisations code tend to be malware ridden.  If  you can't get VS2013, then I would build from source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is likley that this refers to the configure option that was set when they compiled Qt.
This option is explained in detail here: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/11/27/qt-weekly-21-dynamic-opengl-implementation-loading-in-qt-5-4/

To summarise, Qt can be compiled to use ether the desktop OpenGL (a direct interface to the graphics driver provided OpenGL version) or to use Angle (a version of OpenGL that uses directX to provide hardware GL support).

Using 'desktop' gives you the latest (and deprecated) OpenGL features where available, but some drivers do not work properly.

Qt now relies on OpenGL to do important 2D rendering and can be badly affected by faulty drivers. For this reason you have the safer option of Angle, safer but limited to OpenGL ES 2.0 functionality.

Dinamic is a new option that will select between them automatically at runtime on the user's machine. It does however mean that you will need to use the Qt OpenGL API (rather than e.g. GLEW) to access OpenGL.

If you are not going to use OpenGL directly in your code then you should  chose dynamic.

You should also consider compiling the code for yourself, as you are trusting your and your user's security to tver-soft.org. Even without malicious intent these files may be a security risk.